# Ubuntu 16 bridge created but can't browse website

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, ethernet

- Machine X - Running Ubuntu Desktop 16
- Machine Y - Running Windows 8

I have successfully created a bridge on Ubuntu machine. Machine Y can browse websites. But Machine X is unable to browse website.

However on Machine X, ping requests to 8.8.8.8 get a reply. **I need to be able to surf websites on Machine X.**

Please help.

I created a bridge by following https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections tutorial.

Interfaces file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo br0
iface lo inet loopback

# Set up interfaces manually, avoiding conflicts with, e.g., network manager
iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth1 inet manual

# Bridge setup
iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports eth0 eth1
    address 192.168.0.2
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Hi! Would you please, post the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` on Machine X?

Comment: result of cat /etc/resolv.conf on MachineX: #Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN nameserver 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Tiger4020 got the issue. Your nameserver is yourself/localhost/127.0.0.1. Unless you're running a DNS server on that box just set it to your router IP (if it supports that) or just point it to a free public DNS server at 8.8.8.8 If you statically configure IP settings in network manager set DNS there. If you did it manually add a `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8` line to your `/etc/network/interfaces` config file